# Apache2 Permanent Redirect

Tags: apache-http-server

Hi I'm trying to have multiple Redirect rules, that do not work together.

```
Redirect permanent /index.php/news/ http://newurl.io/blog/
Redirect permanent /index.php/1363-2/ http://newurl.io/bar/
Redirect permanent / http://newurl.io/foo/
```

But everytime I add the last rule, the result for `index.php/news/` is a redirect to `http://newurl.io/foo/`.

I tried if the order of the entries effect the result, but they don't.

Is there some way to make Apache only redirect the specific URLs that are being specified by the command?

Comment: You specified that everything should be redirected so it's doing what you want? Where are you actually putting those rules? What does the other configuration look like?

Comment: The config is in hosts.conf, and basically it works, the only problem is, that I want specific addresses to go to another specific address, but currently the redirect is on a first catch basis (so if it sees / it will redirect to foo/ instead of reading ahead and seeing that the url matches another redirect.